# Plugin - read post into blank page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I wonder if I could produce a blank page (not within theme) and write something to it - I need my custom page. I know about WP Ajax, but it's not that simple, cos I wanted to be able to get some data crossdomain (with PHP and regexp) but Im not sure with that.

Simply: I want bypass the theme (and its design) and give a blank page with custom plugin output. (Would be nice to be able to use WP functions)

**Is it possible, or I have to use WP Ajax?**
Thank you

---

Edit1: I want to add something like post with it's permalink (following permalink structure), but without using theme - just blank page with data created by plugin

I know about including WP into external PHP files. I dont want any external file - it should be working within plugin

Comment: You basically want to use WP functions outside of the WP framework? Is that what's you're saying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it with a page template, or if you have to do it from a plugin add a rewrite rule to set a specific url for the "page"